# Clustered/non-clustered index on unique identifier column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, indexing, uniqueidentifier

I have read the various questions/answers here that basically indicate that having a clustered index on a uniqueidentifier column is a poor choice for performance reasons. Regardless, I need to use a uniqueidentifier as my primary key, and I do NOT want to use newsequentialid() because the generated values are too similar to one another (I need more random IDs so users can't [reasonably] 'guess' another ID).

So, what is the best way to index this PK? Even though a clustered index on this column is not ideal, is it better than a "unique, non-clustered" index?

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, if you are trying to use `NEWID()` to achieve randomness (more than just looking random), you're in trouble.

It's usually less than ideal choice because other indexes will reference the clustered index key and a long clustered index key will degrade the performance of all indexes. You could create an `IDENTITY` integer column and make that the clustered index and just create a non-clustered unique index on the `uniqueidentifier` column.