# SQL Server : MERGE performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, sqlperformance

I have a database table with 5 million rows. The clustered index is auto-increment identity column. There PK is a code generated 256 byte `VARCHAR` which is a SHA256 hash of a URL, this is a non-clustered index on the table.

The table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[store_image](
    [imageSHAID] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [imageGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [imageURL] [nvarchar](2000) NOT NULL,
    [showCount] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [imageURLIndex]  AS (CONVERT([nvarchar](450),[imageURL],(0))),
    [autoIncID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_imageSHAID] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [imageSHAID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [autoIncPK] ON [dbo].[store_image] 
(
    [autoIncID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

- `imageSHAID` is a SHA256 hash of an image URL e.g. "http://blah.com/image1.jpg", it is hashed into a varchar of 256 length.
- `imageGUID` is a code generated guid in which I identify the image (it will be used as an index later, but for now I have omitted this column as an index)
- `imageURL` is the full URL of the image (up to 2000 characters)
- `showCount` is the number of times the image is shown, this is incremented each time this particular image is shown.
- `imageURLIndex` is a computed column limited by 450 characters, this allows me to do text searches on the imageURL should I choose to, it is indexable (again index is omitted for brevity)
- `autoIncID` is the clustered index, should allow faster inserting of data.

Periodically I merge from a temp table into the `store_image` table. The temp table structure is as follows (very similar to the store_image table):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[store_image_temp](
    [imageSHAID] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [imageURL] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
    [showCount] [bigint] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

When the merge process is run, I write a `DataTable` to the temp table using the following code:

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(storeConn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity | SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls, null))
{
    bulk.DestinationTableName = "[dbo].[store_image_temp]";
    bulk.WriteToServer(imageTableUpsetDataTable);
}
```

I then run the merge command to update the `showCount` in the `store_image` table by merging from the temp table based on the `imageSHAID`. If the image doesn't currently exist in the `store_image` table, I create it:

```
merge into store_image as Target using [dbo].[store_image_temp] as Source
on Target.imageSHAID=Source.imageSHAID 
when matched then update set 
Target.showCount=Target.showCount+Source.showCount 
when not matched then insert values (Source.imageSHAID,NEWID(), Source.imageURL, Source.showCount);
```

I'm typically trying to merge 2k-5k rows from the temp table to the `store_image` table at any one merge process.

I used to run this DB on a SSD (only SATA 1 connected) and it was very fast (under 200 ms). I ran out of room on the SSD so I swapped the DB to a 1TB 7200 cache spinning disk, since then completion times are over 6-100 seconds (6000 - 100000MS). When the bulk insert is running I can see disk activity of around 1MB-2MB/sec, low CPU usage.

Is this a typical write time for this amount of data? It seems a little slow to me, what is causing the slow performance? Surely with the `imageSHAID` being indexed we should expect quicker seek times than this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` clause in the `MERGE` updates `showCount`. This requires a key lookup on the clustered index.

However, the clustered index is also declared non-unique. This gives information to the optimiser even though the underlying column is unique.

So, I'd make these changes

- the clustered primary key to be `autoIncID`
- the current PK on `imageSHAID` to be a standalone unique index (not constraint) and add an INCLUDE for `showCount`. Unique constraints can't have INCLUDEs

More observations:

- you don't need `nvarchar` for the hash or URL columns. These are not unicode.
- A hash is also fixed length so can be `char(64)` (for SHA2-512).
- The length of a column defines how much memory to assign to the query. See this for more: [is there an advantage to varchar(500) over varchar(8000)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009694/is-there-an-advantage-to-varchar500-over-varchar8000)

Comment: Hello, this seems to have improved things greatly, I have rnu some tests and the merge times seem lower:3.7k @ 24 seconds
2.6k @ 2.4 seconds
2.8k @ 11 seconds
1.3k @ 1.1 seconds
2.6k @ 2.5 seconds
2.1k @ 2.6 seconds, do these merge times seem appropriate? Would rectifying the "other observation" improve further? I figured a 2-3k row merge would always take less than 500ms.

Comment: The other observations would reduce disk and memory use, less bytes to shift around (eg transaction log). And help the optimiser to allocate memory efficiently.

Comment: I'm still getting poor performance even after your suggested alterations. I have some merges lasting 70 seconds plus. Given that I have made the changes to the index/PK can you explain what is happening when I call the merge, surely it is using a index seek on the imageSHAID standalone unique index, which should be fast no?

Comment: The clustering index being on autoIncID really helped performance. Accepting as answer.